# Conference proceeding after journal article

Tags: publications, conference, proceedings

Is it possible to write a conference proceeding about topics already published (by the same author, of course) in a journal article? It is understood that all the sentences will be rephrased and all the figures changed not to fall into self-plagiarism. In a conference, in fact, one often wants to summarize and gather together the results he has obtained in the last months of research.

Comment: This will probably depend heavily on the field. In mathematics, you don't really decide to "write" a conference proceeding; you just present at a conference, and then the proceeding comes out of it as a side effect (if it does -- most conferences don't have proceedings at all). In that case, it can easily happen that the proceeding comes out later than the "final" journal publication. There are various ways to deal with it, starting with not caring about it at all, and ending at adding extra material to the proceedings to make it stand apart. No one usually worries about self-plagiarism.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Do you know how the situation is in the Physics field?

Comment: No. I can only offer experience from mathematics and rumors from computer science :(

Comment: Most computer science conferences explicitly forbid submission of manuscripts that have been accepted to a journal (or another conference).  Even if you rewrite the text, a conference submission describing only previously published work is almost certain to be rejected for lack of novelty.  (As @jakebeal points out, there are exceptions, but in my experience this usually means presenting a recent paper in a journal explicitly tied to the conference.)

Comment: You have a misconception about self-plagiarism. It isn't the using of different words and figures that is the issue, but the need for citation of the older work. If you don't cite it, then it is self plagiarism. The words used are a different matter, perhaps copyright or not depending on who holds copyright. You can quote yourself extensively, but you need to cite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the particulars of your situation, there are three paths I am aware of for presentation at a conference:

1. Some conferences have begun to offer "journal first" submission options that explicitly welcome the presentation of an article that has already been presented in a journal.  For these, one prepares a short precis of the article for review and it is explicitly understood that this has already been published.
2. If you have some new results, you can certainly write a conference paper on these new results as an incremental advance over the prior work. Here, you simply focus on the new results just as you would for any publication building on prior work.  The only question is whether the new results will be considered significant enough for separate publication by your reviewers.
3. Finally, some conferences don't involve peer-reviewed articles at all, but just have one-paragraph abstracts submitted as "applications to speak", in which case figures and self-plagiarism don't enter into the question at all, since the abstract is not a publication in any meaningful sense.

From what you have written, it sounds like the first or second path would apply for your needs.